# How to prevent MouseUp event after DoubleClick on Window TitleBar in WPF?

Tags: wpf

If user double-clicks window title bar to maximize window, the window will maximize on MouseDown event of the second click, but then the MouseUp event on that same second click will be registered by one of the controls in the window that are now under the cursor and trigger something user didn't want.
How can it be prevented?

Comment: Usually , when handling a routed event and the event source matters, you have to handle the event in code-behind and filter the `RotedEventArgs.Source` or `RoutedEventArgs.OriginalSource` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work just fine:

Solution:

```
  //WNDPROC INTEROP
        private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3;

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
            source.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

   private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        //TITLE BAR DOUBLE CLICK
        if (msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("titlebar double click  " + this.WindowState);

            //WINDOW ABOUT TO GET MAXIMIZED
            if (msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK) 
                handleNextMouseup = true;

            else if (msg == 0x202) //  mouseup     
            {        
                if (handleNextMouseup) 
                    handled = true;      
                
                handleNextMouseup = false;     
            } 
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

another possible solution:

```
  //WNDPROC INTEROP
        private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3;

        protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
            HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
            source.AddHook(WndProc);
        }

        private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
        {
            //TITLE BAR DOUBLE CLICK
            if (msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("titlebar double click  " + this.WindowState);

                //WINDOW ABOUT TO GET MAXIMIZED
                if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
                {
                    fakehittestvisible = true;

                }
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }


        private bool fakehittestvisible = false;

        //ON PREVIEW MOUSE UP ABORT IF MIXIMIZING HAPPENED
        private void this_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (fakehittestvisible)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                fakehittestvisible = false;
                return;
            }

            fakehittestvisible = false;
            Console.WriteLine("this mouse up state is " + this.WindowState);
        }
```

Comment: That was a good thinking but I have simplified it with `if (msg == WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK)
    handleNextMouseup = true;
else if (msg == 0x202) //mouseup
    {
        if (handleNextMouseup) handled = true;
        handleNextMouseup = false;
    }` If you make an edit I'll accept it

Comment: Hi I didn't find the WndProc handled to be working with the e.handled on any of the window mouse events..

Comment: I don't know about PreviewMouseUp, but settings `handled=true` on `0x202` in WndProc definitely prevents that event bubbling to any control with `OnMouseUp` in the window